# Show that $|\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2m}| < \epsilon$ holds for all $m, n > \frac{1}{\epsilon}.$

Tags: real-analysis, quadratics, cauchy-sequences

In Example 1.5-9 of the book *Functional Analysis* by Kreyszig it claims that $|\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2m}| < \epsilon$ holds for all $m, n > \frac{1}{\epsilon}.$

My calculations don't lead to that! :

**1st objection:** wlog let $m>n$ and $m=n+k$ so $$|\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2m}| < \epsilon \implies k-2\epsilon(n)(n+k)<0.$$ Differentiation with respect to $k$ and desiring for the $k-2\epsilon(n)(n+k) $ to decrease after its 'right-zero' gives $n > \frac{1}{2\epsilon} $ and thus $m, n > \frac{1}{2\epsilon}.$

**2nd objection:** $k-2\epsilon(n)(n+k)= k-2\epsilon n^2 -2\epsilon nk <0$ holds for $n> \dfrac{-2\epsilon k + \sqrt{4{\epsilon}^2k^2+8\epsilon k}}{4\epsilon k}$. How change of $k$ doesn't effect $k-2\epsilon n^2 -2\epsilon nk <0$?

**3rd objection:** how intersection of two domains for $n,m$ obtained in 1st and 2nd objections is a superset of $n,m > \frac{1}{\epsilon}? $

Comment: How is the `algebra-precalculus` tag relevant when you've used differentiation?

Comment: @Shaun, isn't it algebra minus precalculus? ;-)

Comment: Very clever, but no. The dash is used instead of a space because a space is used to end the current tag name when typing it in.

Comment: @Shaun, I know I was kidding :-)) but I didn't know that  algebra-precalculus shouldn't be used for differentiation content. I'll edit.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. And thank you $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$m,n>{1\over\epsilon}$ implies that ${1\over 2n}<\epsilon/2$. This implies that $|{1\over 2n}-{1\over 2m}|\leq |{1\over 2n}|+|{1\over 2m}|<\epsilon/2+\epsilon/2=\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a little better.

I write $c$ for $\epsilon$
because lazy.

Since
$m, n > \frac1{c}
$,
$0 \le \frac1{m}, \frac1{n}
\le c
$.

If
$m = n$
then
$|\frac1{m}-\frac1{n}|
= 0 < c$.

If
$m > n$
then
$|\frac1{m}-\frac1{n}|
=\frac1{n}-\frac1{m}
\lt \frac1{n}
< c$.

If
$m < n$
then
$|\frac1{m}-\frac1{n}|
=\frac1{m}-\frac1{n}
\lt \frac1{m}
< c$.

In all cases,
$|\frac1{m}-\frac1{n}|
< c$
so that
$|\frac1{2m}-\frac1{2n}|
< \frac{c}{2}$.